# How do I stop getting notifications to Try Safari on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, safari, notifications

I'm getting these stupid reminders to TRY SAFARI. As I don't trust Apple, how do I stop them from trying to push products on me on my personal system where in my opinion, these advertisements should not even be allowed at all?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off notifications in Safari in Notification Centre in settings:

[image: settings]

Set it to None.

Comment: It does not work, because it's not "Safari notification" but "Notification about Safari". Notification comes from the `UIAgent` service (not listed in `Notification Center`) and not Safari itself!